# Function only works in Opera

Tags: javascript, debugging, bbcode

I wonder if I could get some direction on this problem. I have a forum with a js function to surround text in a message with bb code, but it only works in Opera. In other browsers, it just doesn't do anything, the highlighted words just become not highlighted any more. The actual parser to convert from bbcode to html works fine, its just this surroundText function which is not working.

Here is the routine:

```
$('.surroundText').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var before = $(this).data('text'),
        after  = $(this).data('text-after');
    surroundText(before, (after) ? after : '');
});
```

Ultimately I am going to have to install some debugging software and deal with this, but could someone see anything here which is fixable? For some reason Opera works perfectly and everything else doesn't, for a few minor functions on the platform. This is the biggest one.

Edit: Oh and the buttons have this code:

```
<a class="bold" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="surroundText('[b]', '[/b]'); return false;" title="Bold">Bold</a>
```

This is from a working sample...the code is the same, I was confused. Can anyone see a clear problem?

Comment: Can you post `surroundText` please.

Comment: And please alst tell us which Opera do you mean. The original one (up to and including version 12) or the Webkit fork (from version 15 ongoing).

Comment: Ok provided the surroundText and found maybe the problem...Opera is 12

Comment: Here you have stated 'surroundText' as a function in your HTML and a class in your jquery call to click event. If surroundText is function then where is the function declaration. The jquery code implies that you are calling some function on elements with class 'surroundText'

Comment: Well, due to the complexity of the code I don't know quite where that call is, but as it works in Opera, it must be in there or it couldn't work at all.

Comment: You may need to pass the first parameter to the function. On the anchor onclick please pass the innerHTML() or HTML() or text() or val() of some elements or div which you want to enclose text

Comment: <textarea name="message" id="dis-thread-message" tabindex="10"></textarea> is where the text is, the div the text is in. outside of that is a div simply called class="h-group"

Comment: Hmm, I am playing with jfiddle and it seems to be working fine. SSS, could you show me what you think I should do? My skills are limited.

Comment: Spoke too soon, it does not work in jsfiddle

Comment: Still having trouble, trying to figure out how to pass the right parameter on to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured this out, its so simple. The jQuery wasn't loading in the other browsers at all. The issue was pretty simple,

When the JavaScript was loaded, the line looked like this:

```
.script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js").wait()
```

and the problem was that the `http:` isn't supposed to be there, therefore jQuery wasn't loaded at all.

So the proper line is:

```
.script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js").wait()
```